# Why does it display vertically?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

This is what is displaying to me
[image: This is what is displaying to me]

This is what is supposed to look like
[image: This is what is supposed to look like]

I've tried to put some br and look how it behaves and see the code, and it is exactly the same as the guy that I'm doing the tutorial. I just don't understand how it shows differently since we're doing the same project.
I even did the project again just to see if I missed something. I am definitely missing something here, I just don't know what. There's 2 columns, but the first one shows everything vertically. I even added more words and it just adjusts to fit vertically. Everything happens exactly like the teacher but when I add the padding: 0 19%; 0 to the top and bottom and 19% to the sides, that's when it displays different. I'm using Microsoft Edge.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- boxicons link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">

    <!-- remixicon link-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@3.4.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- google fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">COC-STATS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Town hall</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Troops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></div>
    </header>
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h5>#2 Trending</h5>
            <h4>Lead Supercell</h4>
            <h1>GOBLINS</h1>
            <p>Join millions of players worldwide as you build your village, <br> raise a clan, and compete in epic Clan Wars!! </p>
            <a href="#">Compare</a>
            <a href="#" class="ctaa"><i class="ri-play-fill"></i>Watch Gameplay!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-img">
            <img src="img-removebg.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 33px 9%;
    background: transparent;
}

.logo{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

header ul{
    display: flex;
}

header ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: all .55s ease;
}

header ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#menu-icon{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.hero{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(245.59deg, #4d9559 0%, #38703d 28.53%, #133917 75.52%);
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2rem;
}

section{
    padding: 0 19%;
}
```

Comment: I set up your code and it looked like it's "supposed to" in my browser. What browser are you using? That said, I would suggest learning web design from a different tutorial or book. some of them aren't very good these days. :-(

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge and the teacher is using Google Chrome. Might the browser be rendering differently from Chrome?

Comment: Quite possibly. But if the layout is rendering so differently in different browsers, it suggests the layout itself is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly set up a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Vasil-Verdouw/pen/jOQLqbd) so others won't have to copy and paste your code. Seems to render the way it's supposed to. I'm also on Microsoft Edge.

I'm guessing by the name of your image at

```html
<div class="hero-img">
    <img src="img-removebg.png" alt="">
</div>
```

you've made the image yourself someway. Now the only thing I can think of is that your image is wider than the one used by the original, thus pushing the text to be like that.

Maybe try using a different image or just zooming out to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I took the second image from the teacher project. Mine doesn't show the same way even though I have the same code. It's so strange since everyone says the code displays correctly, but for me it doesn't. So confusing.

Comment: I installed another browser and tested it. It shows the same thing. So it isn't from the browser. I also remade the entire project but this time only copying from the teacher, and it still gave me the same result. I still haven't found the problem or even if there's one, but what I know, is that the guy that's doing the tutorial has a different website than mine even though we have the same code.

Comment: The only different from his project is the image. My image is different from his. Might that be why is it showing differently to me?

Comment: I found the problem. Thank you for the help. It was indeed the image. My image is very big and that's why the text is displaying so narrowly. How can I make it smaller enough so it shows like it's supposed too?

Comment: @FábioGonçalves I think you could use `<img ... width="400" />` like I've used in the codepen. Although if differences like this keep happening it might be an idea to look for a different tutorial. But that's a judgement you'll have to make for yourself. Btw, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question.